# Can't mount music CD (maybe anticopy protection?)

Tags: mount

I'm trying to play a music CD on my Debian machine, but when I'm trying to mount the CD using `mount /dev/sr0` (using /etc/fstab options), I get this:

```
{12:16:49} [~]  → sudo mount /dev/sr0
mount: /media/cdrom0: can't read the superblock at /dev/sr0.
```

The disk works on Windows. I've installed `udftools` and nothing.

`dmesg` gives me this log:

```
[123956.786209] UDF-fs: error (device sr0): udf_read_tagged: read failed, block=256, location=256
[123956.814324] UDF-fs: error (device sr0): udf_read_tagged: read failed, block=512, location=512
[123956.850415] UDF-fs: error (device sr0): udf_read_tagged: read failed, block=256, location=256
[123956.890356] UDF-fs: error (device sr0): udf_read_tagged: read failed, block=512, location=512
[123956.926283] UDF-fs: error (device sr0): udf_read_tagged: read failed, block=256, location=256
[123956.962261] UDF-fs: error (device sr0): udf_read_tagged: read failed, block=512, location=512
[123956.962269] UDF-fs: warning (device sr0): udf_fill_super: No partition found (1)
[123957.078216] isofs_fill_super: bread failed, dev=sr0, iso_blknum=16, block=16
[123957.190287] FAT-fs (sr0): unable to read boot sector
```

I checked the similar questions here, and it seems nothing works...

Comment: Is the CD displayed correctly on Windows?

Comment: Yeah, on Windows works fine. I tried to generate an ISO image from CD, but copy protection.

Comment: Please, consider to add more information about your system, like kernel, debian version, and of course, the CD reader model